# Input Text is not changing in the bean variable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, icefaces

When i enter the data in the browser, it should suppose to set the variable parameter in the bean. But it is not setting for some reason. At one point it did work and again not anymore.

### XHMTL

```
<p:panel header="Previous Summary" toggleable="true"
                toggleSpeed="500"
                style="border: 1px solid white; background-color: #F0F8FF; text-align: left;">
                <ice:form>
                    <ice:inputRichText id="editor_prevsummary"
                        value="#{statusReport.prevSummaryStr}" width="1200" height="200"
                        rendered="#{statusReport.renderPrevSummTextIn}"
                        onchange="this.form.submit()"  />


                    <ice:outputText value="#{statusReport.prevSummaryStr}"
                        rendered="#{!statusReport.renderPrevSummTextIn}" escape="false"></ice:outputText>
                    <br />
                    <ice:commandButton action="#{statusReport.editPrevSummary()}"
                        value="Edit" partialSubmit="true" />
                    <ice:commandButton action="#{statusReport.updatePrevSumm()}"
                        partialSubmit="true" value="Update"  />
                </ice:form>
            </p:panel>
```

### Bean Values

```
  public String getExecSummaryStr() {

        return execSummaryStr;
    }

    public void setExecSummaryStr(String execSummary) {

        this.execSummaryStr = execSummary;
    }
```

I getting the same thing, even i change to inputText or anything. Not sure why it is happening and where i should start diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you're using the same variable for the `<ice:inputRichText>` and the `<ice:outputText>` inside the same form. When the form is submitted, the framework will set the value from both components into `#{statusReport.prevSummaryStr}`, leading to odd behavior in your site.

EDIT:

A possible solution could be moving the `<ice:outputText>` out of the form and rendering from your commandButton. Another solution could be using javascript to update its value. You can do something like:

```
<ice:inputRichText id="editor_prevsummary"
    value="#{statusReport.prevSummaryStr}" width="1200" height="200"
    rendered="#{statusReport.renderPrevSummTextIn}"
    onchange="document.getElementById('divText').innerHTML = this.value"  />
<div id="divText">

</div>
```

Comment: @LuiggiMenoza I believe so, can you suggest me now how to get it correct. When i update it, it should show text in outputext.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I've never used IceFaces, but wouldn't the `ice:outputText` behave like an `h:outputText` (only get the value and never try to set it)?

Comment: @eljunior yes, and `<ice:inputRichText>` could work like `<h:inputText>`, if you test a similar sample using pure JSF you will get the same error.

Comment: @CooolAwesome answer updated. Also, IMO would preffer the 2nd way, using JavaScript.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza There is actually save button for ice:inputRichText which resets the bean value. Now it is working after pressing save button.